# Why does Python tkinter label widget not update?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

```
class First_Frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.commandent1=StringVar()
        self.commandent1.set("tutaj bedzie sie pokazywal aktualny status")
        self.img=Image.open("database.XPM","r")
        self.image_true=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.label=Label(self,image=self.image_true).grid()
        self.label2=Label(self,text="twoje gui uzytkownika").grid()
        self.widgets_2()

    def widgets_2(self):
        self.status_text=Label(self,text=self.commandent1.get())
        self.entry1=Entry(self)
        self.entry1.bind("<Return>",self.update_status)
        self.entry1.grid()
        self.status_text.grid()
    def update_status(self):
        self.x=self.entry1.get()
        self.commandent1.set(self.x)
```

Comment: Use this [Hello, Again](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm) as a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main reasons your **Label** *(not text)* widget is not updating.

Reason 1. You need to handle the event that is being passed to `update_status` from the binding. To do this just add `event` or any argument name really you want. I just use `event` for readability.

```
def update_status(self, event):
```

Reason 2. You need to and the less obvious reason here for some is the way you are using your `StringVar()` on the label widget. Here you are assigning the current text value of the `StringVar()` only once and never again. To properly use the `StringVar()` with a label widget you will need to assign the `StringVar()` to a `textvariable` argument and not a `text` argument.

Like this:

```
Label(self,textvariable=self.commandent1).grid()
```

Note I took out the image portion of your code as it was irrelevant to the question. Your final code should look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class First_Frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.commandent1 = StringVar()
        self.commandent1.set("tutaj bedzie sie pokazywal aktualny status")
        Label(self,text="twoje gui uzytkownika").grid()
        self.widgets_2()

    def widgets_2(self):
        self.entry1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry1.bind("<Return>", self.update_status)
        self.entry1.grid()
        Label(self,textvariable=self.commandent1).grid()

    def update_status(self, event):
        self.commandent1.set(self.entry1.get())


root = Tk()
First_Frame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @FilipWeiss If my answer helped you please make sure to select the check mark next to the answer to indicate  your problem was solved.